# Will search engines match search terms with domains that use the domain extension to create the keyword

Tags: seo, domains, search-engines, optimization, search-results

Sorry if I butchered the title/question. Say my name is John Fernandes and my website is "johnfernand.es". If someone Googles "John Fernandes" will it match "**johnfernand**.**es**" like it would "twitter.com/**johnfernandes**"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Domain name benefit in SEO](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/77724/18400).

Comment: Is this considered an "exact match domain"? I kinda doubt it. Is this a "partial match domain"? Well, not really. (?)

Comment: No. That will not work. Cute hack though. However, I often warned against domain name hacks for one simple reason. While it is cute and possibly memorable, they add no value otherwise and can lead to confusion. You will note that most companies are shying away from domain name hacks when just a few years ago it was all the rage. Do it if you want to. It is a cute hack!! Really! It may be a good option for a personal site. But there will be no search value from the domain name added because of it. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary. Google and other Search Engines (SE) rank websites in the Search Engine Results Pages (SERP) based on their usability rating, in accordance to the SE's algorithm. Having said that you need to have content related to the domain name and the website hosted on this web address to be popular and to offer valuable information.